# How to connect to Oracle9i and Oracle 10/11g simultaneously in PHP

Tags: php, oracle

for my project i need to connect to two different oracle DB located in two different servers. 
Which oci should i use in order for me to able to connect to both servers simultaneously in PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just open two connection handles?

```
$conn1 = oci_connect('username', 'password', '9i-connect-string');
$conn2 = oci_connect('username2', 'password', '10g-connect-string');
```

Comment: you missed the most important part of the question - which oci to use?

Comment: The oci package is agnostic of Oracle version. As long as you submit queries compatible to each version on the appropriate connection handle, it doesn't matter. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.oci8.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the newest client, in this case the 11gR2 client. This connects to all your listed versions without problems. You connect using SQL*net.